# Webpy form data isn't formatted

Tags: python, web.py

I'm trying to create a form using web.py lib... I've followed this tutorial:

http://webpy.org/cookbook/forms

But when I try to log the data from the webform I get something like this:

```
Token: <web.form.Textbox object at 0x7fcfeb847590>
IMEI: <web.form.Textbox object at 0x7fcfeb847690>
Latitude: <web.form.Textbox object at 0x7fcfeb847790>
Longitude: <web.form.Textbox object at 0x7fcfeb847890>
Date & Time: <web.form.Textbox object at 0x7fcfeb847990>
```

Do I need to convert the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the `get_value()` method on each `Textbox` object to get its value. Here's a fairly unhelpful [API reference section in the docs on forms](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.form) as well, if you're curious about what methods are available.